# How to determine that a UserControl Collection Property has changed at Design Time?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, .net-2.0

I have a UserControl which has a collection property.  Part of my requirements is that the control's GUI modifies itself in DesignMode based on the contents of the collection.  Think ListBox, for example.

My code looks like this (the override of Add is just an experiment):

```
public partial class MyControl: UserControl
{
    public class StringCollection : List<string>
    {
        public new void Add(string item)
        {
            Console.Beep();
            base.Add(item);
        }
    }       

    [Category("Data")]
    [Description("The items to be displayed in the Control.")] 
    [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design", typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public StringCollection Items
    {
        get
        {
            return mItems;
        }
    }
```

Everything works OK, except for finding out at design time that the Collection has been modified via the StringCollectionEditor.  I get "Beeps" on control creation, and if I add to the collection from code.

I know that this **can** be done, because ListBox does it.  Anyone have any ideas how?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the problem with the *new* keyword, it cannot magically make methods virtual.  The StringCollectionEditor will call IList.Add() to add an item.  That will call List<>.Add(), not your version.  You have to give up on List<> and implement your own collection class that inherits from IList.  That's mostly boring work, you use a List<> to implement it.  Like this:

```
    class StringCollection : System.Collections.IList {
        private List<object> impl = new List<object>();
        public int Add(object value) {
            Console.Beep();
            impl.Add(value);
            return Count;
        }

        public void Clear() {
            impl.Clear();
        }

        // etc...
    }
```

Note how ListBox did this too, it uses ObjectCollection.  Maybe you can use it as well.  Keep in mind that Winforms was created before generics became available.

Comment: THANKS - wiping large quantities of egg from face :-)